# fixing mouse offset causes lag. how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mousemove, lag

i made an HTML5 javascript game and the touch event was offset. when i added 
this.canvas.width = this.canvas.offsetWidth;
this.canvas.height = this.canvas.offsetHeight;

the touch event is fixed, yet the game will lag after some time. what actually happen? how to fix it?

Comment: offsetWidth will cause a reflow which could be causing the slow down in your game, but are you making that call every frame or something?

Comment: i put those lines after i declare to getelementbyid of my canvas @DerekR